# gazebo wg_world.launch doesn't show world

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm running ros fuerte on ubuntu 12.04 in a virtual machine.

I'm trying to run gazebo examples, in this case i want to run this tutorial
"3D Willow Garage Map", but i get this error and an empty world. Somebody knows something about this?

```
gustavo@gustavo-VirtualBox:~$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds wg_world.launch
... logging to /home/gustavo/.ros/log/63666e4c-34e5-11e2-8956-08002725ede9/roslaunch-gustavo-VirtualBox-6173.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server 

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time
 * /wg_walls

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/debug)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)
    xml2factor_wg_walls (gazebo/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [6189]
ROS_MASTER_URI=

setting /run_id to 63666e4c-34e5-11e2-8956-08002725ede9
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6202]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [6216]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [6222]
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:

Reading symbols from /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzserver...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.


Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[xml2factor_wg_walls-4]: started with pid [6234]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Msg Waiting for master.loading model xml from ros parameter
[INFO] [WallTime: 1353617060.820411] [0.000000] waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_gazebo_model
...[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.


[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
.[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0x7fffe6e67700 (LWP 6271)]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0x7fffe6666700 (LWP 6272)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe5e65700 (LWP 6274)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe5664700 (LWP 6275)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe4e63700 (LWP 6276)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcffff700 (LWP 6284)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcf7fe700 (LWP 6285)]
[New Thread 0x7fffceffd700 (LWP 6286)]
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ localhost:11345
[ INFO] [1353617064.781819333]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0x7ffff7e71700 (LWP 6290)]
[Thread 0x7ffff7e71700 (LWP 6290) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffcdc26700 (LWP 6291)]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0x7fffbe883700 (LWP 6293)]
[New Thread 0x7fffbe082700 (LWP 6294)]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]

[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ localhost:11345
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0x7fffb24ca700 (LWP 6306)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb1cc9700 (LWP 6307)]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[ INFO] [1353617068.276592271]: joint trajectory plugin missing <updateRate>, defaults to 0.0 (as fast as possible)
[New Thread 0x7fffb129f700 (LWP 6311)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb0a9e700 (LWP 6348)]
[New Thread 0x7fffa3fff700 (LWP 6349)]
[New Thread 0x7fffa37fe700 (LWP 6356)]
spawn status:  SpawnModel: successfully spawned model
[xml2factor_wg_walls-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/gustavo/.ros/log/63666e4c-34e5-11e2-8956-08002725ede9/xml2factor_wg_walls-4*.log
[ INFO] [1353617071.416806180, 0.140000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1353617071.589785427, 1.277000000]: Starting to spin physics dynamic reconfigure node...
LightListWidget::OnLightMsg
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: No pincher, please call crStateSetCurrentPointers() in your SPU
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
^COpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty elements buffer, ignoring.
[gazebo_gui-3] killing on exit
[gazebo-2] killing on exit
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2:  6230 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
[gazebo-2] escalating to SIGTERM
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
gustavo@gustavo-VirtualBox:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48891/gazebo-wg_world.launch-doesn%27t-show-world/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2012-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can try launching a empty world of gazebo and later try to open the world in gazebo from insert models.

---

Originally posted by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) with karma: 172 on 2012-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2012-11-29**:
Hi, @joseescobar60 I did what you said and i can open the wg world, but I think that this world is imported from share folder in stageros package instead of import it from world folder. I need to open it from there because i have another custom worlds that i need to use.

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-01-09**:
After inserting models to gazebo (e.g. a woman) I can teleop Turtlebot to collide with the inserted model. But strangely, in rviz the robot cannot sense the model. Somehow the inserted model only exists in gazebo but not in rviz. Do you experience this problem?